# Is there an integral formula for the Hadamard product of exponential generating functions?

Tags: generating-functions, formal-power-series

For two ordinary generating functions $F(x) = \sum_i f_i x^i$ and $G(x) = \sum_i g_i x^i$, one can compute

$$(F \odot G)(x) = \sum_i f_i g_i x^i = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} F(\sqrt{x} e^{it}) G(\sqrt{x} e^{-it}) dt$$

Is there something similar for exponential generating functions of the form $F(x) = \sum_i f_i \frac{x^i}{i!}$?

Comment: I won't be able to answer your question anyway, but I would like at least to understand it. Are you wanting something like $\sum_i\frac{a_ib_i}{i!^2}x^i=\int A(\dots)B(\dots)$ with $A(x)=\sum_i\frac{a_i}{i!}x^i$ and $B(x)=\sum_i\frac{b_i}{i!}x^i$? If so, why not apply the formula you gave to $f_i=\frac{a_i}{i!}$ and $g_i=\frac{b_i}{i!}$? So your question must be something else, but what?

Comment: I suppose my difficulty is the pesky factor of $1/i!$. It would nice to be able to find $\sum_i f_i g_i \frac{x^i}{i!} = ...$. If I know $\sum_i f_i \frac{x^i}{i!} = F(x)$, I would still need to find $\sum_i g_i x^i$, but I might only know $\sum_i g_i \frac{x^i}{i!} = G(x)$. So I wonder if there's an easier method of doing this given F and G, rather than expanding G as a power series, deleting the factors of $1/i!$, trying to find a closed form for that sum, then doing the Hadamard product integral